# webClient возвращает 403 или 500

Tags: c#, blockchain

Хочу узнать данные по этой ссылке

```
response = webClient.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1E2P55rwqpac54VQDBEXz9jXcYMNWzTAXF");
```

Постоянно выдает 403 или 500 ошибку. Хотя в браузере все ОК.
Добавлял `Header`, ошибка продолжается

Если кто знает решение, помогите достать ответ

Comment: Проверено, что у себя, что [онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z0dGGb), все прекрасно работает. Ищите проблему у себя.

Comment: Первая ошибка характерна для случаев, когда вам запретили доступ, например за слишком частые запросы. Вторая - когда у сервера проблемы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Покажите как вы делаете? я лично делаю вот так `using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()){response = webClient.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1E2P55rwqpac54VQDBEXz9jXcYMNWzTAXF");}`